# $parent binding not required in template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Example at https://jsfiddle.net/btriplett/y3p8cdby/2/

I'm experiencing some confusing behavior with the $parent tag in knockout.  I was experimenting with contextually removing items in a list and was expecting to have to use the $parent tag to access the parent viewmodel's remove function (see below).

Here is the markup:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: list">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the viewmodel

```
var data = [ {name: "Bob"}, {name:"Joe"}, {name: "John"}];

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.list = ko.observableArray(data);

    self.remove = function(item){
        self.list.remove(item);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
```

However, this doesn't work.  I get (in Chrome with knockout 3.0).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return list }"
Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return $parent.remove }"
Message: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

but **if I remove the $parent it works!**  This is not at all what I expected because the context of the list item is the item and not the viewmodel.  Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewModel is a constructor that should be called with `new`. Or (I would recommend) change the first line of it to

```
var self = {};
```

and call it as you have here.

Comment: And by convention it should be capitalized, yes?

Comment: @KennethK. Right, constructors should begin with capitals.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can make your classes not fail when you forget to call `new` on them.

```
function ViewModel(params) {
    if (!(this instanceof ViewModel)) {
        return new ViewModel(params);
    }

    ...
}
```